# Географические координаты и расстояния в MySQL

Tags: mysql, координаты

Для вычисления расстояния до ближайших объектов от другого объекта требуется хранить координаты в MySQL. Почитав другие темы, понял, что лучше всего использовать тип POINT и создать SPATIAL индекс для ускорения поиска.

Как составить запрос, который из таблицы objects (имеющей поле coord типа POINT) выбрать, к примеру, 5 ближайших объектов к другой точке и рассчитать для них расстояния?

И второй вопрос, как рассчитать расстояние от объектов до Черного моря (точнее до ближайшего его берега). Пока что понял, что надо описать его полигон.

Comment: это смотрели http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points ?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо, с первым вопросом стало яснее

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том, что для вычисления расстояния на земле по координатам, используется сложная формула:

[image: Расчет расстояния по дуге]

Есть ее реализации, например, [на php](https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/calculation-of-distances-between-cities-on-their-coordinates/). Естественно, ее расчет в mysql может серьезно ударить по производительности. Такая формула нужна из-за того, что расстояния по ней рассчитываются по дуге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так-же следует отметить что один градус долготы имеет разную длину в зависимости от широты. Так на экваторе 1 градус долготы ~111км, и постепенно уменьшается до нуля при движении к полюсам.

Если использовать простой запрос, как [предлагают тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006654/fastest-way-to-find-distance-between-two-lat-long-points), это будет неверно хотя-бы потому, что 1 градус широты не равен 1 градусу долготы. Вы можете пренебречь кривизной земли, если расстояния между объектами небольшие. Тогда Вы можете посчитать расстояния, по простой формуле Пифагора, но вам нужно добавить коэффициенты, рассчитанные для конкретной точки земной поверхности.

Так для черного моря 1 градус долготы будет ~81.3 км, а 1 градус широты всегда одинаков, ~111.3км.

Расстояние до берега вы можете посчитать, посчитав расстояния до его точек и выбрав наименьшее.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ! С первым вопросом уже разобрался. Как и писал выше, использовал тип point и функцию st_distance_sphere, которая учитывает разные величины широты и долготы. А для второго вопроса наверное создам другую тему, так как понял, что для этой цели лучше использовать api карт.